# Unable to cast object of type 'NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFCell' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, npoi

I am using NPOI to read the excel spreadsheet .I am gettting the above mentioned error at code dr["Amount"] = row.GetCell(4).  Could somebody tell me what the problem is.

```
     XSSFWorkbook xssfwb;
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(excelPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                xssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            }

            var sheet = xssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); // Change this to the worksheet you want to import.
            var rows = sheet.GetRowEnumerator();
            var dtExcelData = new DataTable();
            var linenumber = 0;
            DataRow dr;


            dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { 
            new DataColumn("AccountNumber", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(decimal)),
            new DataColumn("Sedol",typeof(string)) });
        while (rows.MoveNext())
        {
            var row = (XSSFRow)rows.Current;
            linenumber++;



   if (row.GetCell(0) != null)
            {
                dr = dtExcelData.NewRow();
                dr["AccountNumber"] = row.GetCell(1).ToString();
                dr["Amount"] = row.GetCell(4);
                dr["Sedol"] = row.GetCell(11).ToString();

                dtExcelData.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If `Amount` is a number and you're sure about its value why don't you use `row.GetCell(4).NumericCellValue`?

Comment: I am geting error  Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell

Comment: Then (if you can't set cell format to Number) you have to read it as string and parse it (as suggested by Shannon). Format may (also) be incorrect because of decimal separator (check what your culture info is and what you have inside your sheet).

Comment: I set the datacolumn of databale column amount as string type and then parsed it as decimal as per shanon's suggestion but i am getting an errror Input string was not in correct format.

Comment: If you set to string why do you need to parse? I think one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to place an object into a decimal field. You might try

`dr["Amount"] = decimal.parse(row.GetCell(4).toString());`

to see if that fixes your error.

Comment: Nope. I get an error Input string was not in the correct format.

Comment: Is the string a value that can be parsed or converted to a decimal format?  You might try `Convert.ToDecimal(string) or Convert.ToDecimal(string,culture)`